# explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)

Tags: c, iar

i am trying to develop a project with IAR.
here is the error message:
Error[Pe260]: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)

Regards.

When i try:
void send_data_byte(unsigned char dattt) {
i see a new error:
Error[Pe159]: declaration is incompatible with previous "send_data_command"

my sen_data_command function in is on the below

```
send_data_byte(unsigned char dattt){  
   for(j=0;j<8;j++){  
 pwmstart(1);  
 pwmstop(18);  
  if(dattt & 0x01){  
    __delay_cycles(1687);
  dattt=dattt>>1;  
  }  
 else  
  {  
 __delay_cycles(562); 
   dattt=dattt>>1;  
  }  
  }  
 pwmstop(1);  


  }
```

```
  void send_data_command(unsigned char dat){  

 for (int r=0;r<160;r++)
   {pwmstart(1);}  
 for (int y=0;y<80;y++)
   {pwmstop(1);} 
  send_data_byte(dat);  
  repeat();  
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly declare the function's return type. In this case if you have nothing to return, you should declare it as `void`:

```
void send_data_byte(unsigned char dattt) {
```

Comment: i tried, but there is a new error. i added details. can you take look again, please?

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicate that, you don't explicitly declare any return type of function `send_data_type`. and it suggesting to put a `int` before `send_data_type`. Error massage suggest u to write it in following way:

```
int send_data_byte(unsigned char dattt) {
```

You can also write declare the function as void if you don't need to return anything.

```
void send_data_byte(unsigned char dattt) {
```

There are one more error in your code is that, in function `send_data_byte` you don't declare `j`. The following part of the code

```
send_data_byte(unsigned char dattt){  
for(j=0;j<8;j++){
```

should be,

```
send_data_byte(unsigned char dattt){  
int j;
for(j=0;j<8;j++){
```

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of the C language, prior to 1999, had an "implicit `int`" rule. If you declared a function without specifying the return type, it would be assumed to return a result of type `int`. The 1999 standard dropped this rule, and made it mandatory to specify the return type on any function declaration or definition. Many compilers cater to old code by permitting such declarations, or by diagnosing them with a non-fatal warning.

Even in pre-1999 C there was no real reason to take advantage of the "implicit `int`" rule. If a function returns an `int` result, you can always declare it that way explicitly. (*Very* old C, before 1989, didn't have `void`, but support for post-1989 C is essentially universal now.)

As for your other error:

```
Error[Pe159]: declaration is incompatible with previous "send_data_command"
```

it indicates that you have two declarations, or a declaration and a definition, of `send_data_command`, and they differ in some way. There's only one occurrence of `send_data_command` in your question, so you haven't shown us the code that causes that error. Make sure all references to `send_data_command` in your program are consistent, and make sure a declaration -- specifically a prototype (which specifies the types of any parameters) -- is visible any time you call it.

(Incidentally, your code would be much easier to read if it were indented properly. There are automated tools that can help you do this. Indentation should reflect the nested structure of your code.)